# How do I unittest a Windows Forms method which has a message box displayed in between

Tags: c#, nunit

I am writing a unit test script for a Windows Forms application and one of my methods pops up a message box, but I don't want to click <kbd>OK</kbd> in between my unit tests. If I do so, it will break the automated unit testing concept.

I searched several posts, but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for this issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are wanting to display a `MessageBox` without it effecting the unit testing of the method? Could give it its own `Task`. Though, not sure how good of practice it is

Comment: From what I understand unit tests shouldn't be testing UI. MessageBox = UI, this method is not unit-testable.

Comment: I think you should consider using an External Testing package like [SmartBears TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/). There are, of course, many other products out there.

Comment: @Sinatr You are correct. Your code should not be tightly-coupled to the UI. If you are trying to test UI or other Framework methods, then that is a code smell that hints at the fact that your code is tightly coupled with the UI or framework.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/